# Setting Category Axis Label Step Dynamically in Kendo Chart

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have implemented the Kendo line chart using following code for category axis

```
categoryAxis: {
categories: model.CycleDateRangeList,
        labels: {
        template: '#= kendo.toString(new Date(value), "dd")#',
                step:2
        },
        baseUnit: "days",
        majorGridLines: {
        visible: false
        }
}
```

This is working great.Currently Labels step are set to 2. I want to set them to 1 on chart click how can I achieve this using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the setOptions() method of the chart to update the step property of the axis:

```
chart.setOptions({ categoryAxis: { labels: {step: 1} } });
```

API Doc:  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-setOptions

Demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/Ohino